# HTML float number for Input min attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I have this short example

```html
<input value="2" min="0.1" max="1000" type="number" />
```

The input with: min=0.1 max=1000 value=2 step=1
The problem is: If I click on up arrow (pseudo-element for number type=number) - the input value becames 2.1 and then 3.1
WHY does it add 0.1 on the first click? And if you change 3.1 to 3 and click up arrow you still see 3.1 and 4.1 on the second click

Comment: It works for float min number only. If min is 0 or something else (int number) everything works fine

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/step#min_impact_on_step: _"The value of `min` and `step` define what are valid values"_ Your minimum is specified as `0.1`, and only values that satisfy `min + x * step` are considered valid (with `x` being  an integer greater-equal 0.)

Comment: @CBroe thank you

Answer (score 1):

Adding step attribute solves the problem

```html
<input value="2" min="0.1" max="1000" step="0.1" type="number" />
```

Comment: But I need step="1". And in this way it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use js like below.

```
$(this).off('input').on('input',function(e){
  var value = $(this).val();
  var regExp = /^\d{0,10}(\.\d{0,1})?$/;
  if(!regExp.test(this.value)){
    $(this).val(value.substring(0,value.length-1));
  }
});
```

You can also control length of input or max/min for float. Don't forget to change `this` to your input tag `name`. Good luck! :)